# How do I set up cron to run a file just once at a specific time?

Tags: linux, unix, cron

How do I set up `cron` to run a file just once at a specific time? One of the alternatives is [`at`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_(command)) but it is not accessible to all users on standard hosting plans. Therefore I was wondering whether there is way to do it using `cron`?

Comment: I have tried running `$at = shell_exec('at');` on standart LAMP server and it returned NULL. Therefore I asume it doesn't work (have permissions) by default.

Comment: Is there an easy way to move this to ServerFault?  It seems more appropriate there.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try this out to execute a command on 30th March 2011 at midnight:

```
0 0 30 3 ? 2011  /command
```

**WARNING**: As noted in comments, the *year* column is not supported in standard/default implementations of cron. Please refer to [TomOnTime answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30378554/1760058), for a proper way to run a script at a specific time in the future in standard implementations of cron.

Comment: so this will make it run only once? well, seemingly. However, is there any way to convert timestamp to crong time format?

Comment: You should probably omit the 'Day of week' field by using a question mark (?).

Comment: From Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Special_Characters ... The '?' character is used to omit the specification of a value for the day-of-month and day-of-week fields. Since it's not valid to specify values for both fields, '?' becomes necessary to omit one of either ('*' is considered a specific value).

Comment: If I'm correct, does this add a line every time you execute this? Or will it remove itself from the crontab list after it's done?

Comment: You may edit the crontab file and remove the scheduled job after it has been executed.

Comment: Huh?  When did "year" get added as a column.  Can you explain?

Comment: There is no year in "standard" crontab. But checkout this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724316/how-can-i-specify-time-in-cron-considering-year - some implementations do allow it.

Comment: This will run on March 30 every year for normal "cron"s without a year specification. https://crontab.guru/#0_0_30_3_*

Comment: Downvoted. This answer does not run once, as the original question requests.

Answer (score 89):

You really want to use `at`.  It is exactly made for this purpose.

```
echo /usr/bin/the_command options | at now + 1 day
```

However if you don't have `at`, or your hosting company doesn't provide access to it, you can have a cron job include code that makes sure it only runs once.

Set up a cron entry with a very specific time:

```
0 0 2 12 * /home/adm/bin/the_command options
```

Next /home/adm/bin/the_command needs to either make sure it only runs once.

```
#! /bin/bash

COMMAND=/home/adm/bin/the_command
DONEYET="${COMMAND}.alreadyrun"

export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH

if [[ -f $DONEYET ]]; then
  exit 1
fi
touch "$DONEYET"

# Put the command you want to run exactly once here:
echo 'You will only get this once!' | mail -s 'Greetings!' me@example.com
```

Comment: The + is for "You really want to use at. It is exactly made for this purpose.", because that's so true... I did only just find out about it though; so, why not use it's own CLI? Unless the current interaction perhaps added after 2015, in which case my question isn't really applicable..

Comment: You don't have to `echo` the command into "at".  Its just something I do because eventually I automate everything.

Comment: Hi @Tomontime, I wonder if one can trigger reboot like this (without cron), since that needs sudo/root - like `echo "reboot" | at now + 9 hour`

Comment: @ValterEkholm You can do that.  However you might get better results by using `shutdown` and specifying the right flags to reboot, and to delay by 9 hours.  The benefit of using the shutdown command is that it has built-in facilities to abort a reboot; people might be more familiar with those flags than `atq`.  The downside is that `shutdown` has different flags on Linux, *BSD, Solaris, etc.

Comment: Aha, thanks, now I get the idea - not use "at" / just "shutdown with flags"

Answer (score 31):

You really want to use `at`. It is exactly made for this purpose.

```
echo /usr/bin/the_command options | at now + 1 day
```

However if you don't have `at`, or your hosting company doesn't provide access to it, you could make a self-deleting cron entry.

Sadly, this will remove all your cron entries. However, if you only have one, this is fine.

```
0 0 2 12 * crontab -r ; /home/adm/bin/the_command options
```

The command `crontab -r` removes your crontab entry. Luckily the rest of the command line will still execute.

WARNING: This is dangerous!  It removes ALL cron entries.  If you have many, this will remove them all, not just the one that has the "crontab -r" line!

Comment: Moderator note: this is not a repost of [Tom's other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30378470/100297), this is an alternative answer using a different technique.

Answer (score 4):

You could put a crontab file in `/etc/cron.d` which would run a script that would run your command and then delete the crontab file in `/etc/cron.d`.  Of course, that means your script would need to run as root.

Comment: A similar thing can be achieved without root permissions, see [TomOnTime’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30378554/711006).

Answer (score 1):

Your comment suggests you're trying to call this from a programming language.  If that's the case, can your program fork a child process that calls sleep then does the work?

What about having your program calculate the number of seconds until the desired runtime, and have it call `shell_exec("sleep ${secondsToWait) ; myCommandToRun");`

Comment: You are right: I am trying to run it from PHP. What if the secondsToWait is [..] 60*60*24*30, that is, 30 days? wouldn't it eventually kill the server? (and I need to start more than one job; hundreds [but they must run at different times])

Comment: You didn't say anything in your question about the time being a month away.  Of course that changes things.

Answer (score 1):

For those who is not able to access/install `at` in environment, can use custom script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
echo ""
echo "Syntax Error!"
echo "Usage: $0 <shell script> <datetime>"
echo "<datetime> format: %Y%m%d%H%M"
echo "Example: $0 /home/user/scripts/server_backup.sh 202008142350"
echo ""
exit 1
fi

while true; do
  t=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M);      
  if [ $t -eq $2 ]; then
    /bin/bash $1
    echo DONE $(date);
    break;
  fi;
  sleep 1;
done
```

Let's name the script as **run1time.sh**
Example could be something like:

```
nohup bash run1time.sh /path/to/your/script.sh 202008150300 &
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: @NVS Abhilash this is real working workaround, alternative to at command. Year column in cron is not supported in standard/default implementations.

Answer (score 0):

`at` is the correct way.

If you don't have the `at` command in the machine and you also don't have install privilegies on it, you can put something like this on `cron` (maybe with the `crontab` command):

```
* * * 5 * /path/to/comand_to_execute; /usr/bin/crontab -l | /usr/bin/grep -iv command_to_execute | /usr/bin/crontab -
```

it will execute your command one time and remove it from `cron` after that.