# How can I specify time in CRON considering YEAR?

Tags: linux, cron

My task is to specify time in CRON considering YEAR field. How can i do it, or do u know any stuff which can help me on my linux server? thx

Comment: Workaround: run every year and move the year logic to the script. Personally, I wouldn't really trust a scheduled task that runs less than once a year. Too many things can change until you notice it skipped a run.

Comment: completely agree with u, too many things may happen

Comment: There is another usecase for using YEAR: If you only want execute a Job once.

Comment: @CodeFreezr, if you want to run a job a single time, you should use `at` instead of a crontab. `at` will execute your task a single time, similar as cron does.

Answer (score 15):

As indicated in earlier posts, you cannot indicate a year field, it is, however, possible to mimic it:

```
# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  *   command to be executed
  0  0  1  1  *   [[ $(date "+\%Y") == 2020 ]] && command1
  0  0  1  1  *   (( $(date "+\%Y") % 3 == 0  )) && command2
  0  0  1  1  *   (( $(date "+\%Y") % 3 == 1  )) && command3
```

Here, `command1` will run on the 2020-01-01T00:00:00, `command2` will run every 3 years on the first of January at midnight, it will run so on 2019, 2022, 2025, ... . `command3` does the same as `command2` but has one year offset, i.e. 2020, 2023, 2026, ...

**note:** don't forget that you have to escape the <percent>-character (`%`) in your crontab file:

> The "sixth" field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to be run.  The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or
>   a "`%`" character, will be executed by `/bin/sh` or by the shell specified in the `SHELL` variable of the cronfile.  A "`%`" character in the command, unless escaped with a backslash (`\`), will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first `%` will be sent to the command as standard input.
>
> **<sub>source: `man 5 crontab`</sub>**

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that I had to put a backslash to make the date evaluation work (in `crontab -e`; while it worked good directly in bash): `[[ $(date "+\%Y")`.

Comment: @Kamafeather You are correct, you have to escape the `%` in cron.

Comment: @Kamafeather Nice comment. It's worth it to add it to your answer. thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Crontab (5) file format has no YEAR field. You could try running a cron job @yearly (at 00:00 on New Year's day) which looks at the current year using date(1) and updates the current crontab file to one appropriate for the new year.

Comment: but only feature is in needed for easily rewrite back and forward year field value
unfortunately cumbrous logic

Answer (score 8):

Standard `cron` doesn't support a year field, but it's worth noting that some implementations support an extended crontab format with a sixth `year` field, such as [nnCron](http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm). Not every cron is created equal.

Answer (score -1):

```
var task = cron.schedule('0 0 1 1 *', () => {
    console.log('Printing this line 1ST JANUARY OF EVERY YEAR in the terminal');
});
```

It is work for considering YEAR field.. 
@mart7ini