# How do I parse cron expression with year field in javascript

Tags: javascript, cron

I want to represent a period of time using the cron expressions, and to be able to know whether a date range includes the period described by the cron expression.

The problem is that the year field (7th) is not part of the standard cron specification, according to this question: [How can I specify time in CRON considering YEAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724316/how-can-i-specify-time-in-cron-considering-year)

However, there are some cron expression parsers that support this 7th year field, like this one: https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

I've already tried some libraries like [cron-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron-parser), but none of them support the year field.

Does anyone know a library that could suit my needs, or some possible simple workaround?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but this is a perfectly valid expression to run every 2 year.. `0 0 0 ? * * 2017/2`

Comment: Is it? I can't find any javascript library that can parse this kind of expression

Comment: Ah okay, let me see if I can write something up for you or find one, now in understand the question

Comment: This one seems to be working.. http://bradymholt.github.io/cRonstrue/#cronstrue-demo DEMO at the bottom

Comment: this seems to be working according to the demo field. Just for my information, how did you find it?

Comment: I just had a look for `javascript parse cron 7` but only checked the demo's of them very quickly! :d

Comment: @Pogrindis thank you but I have some more requirements that aren't covered by this library. I update my question