# Celery, run task once at a specified time

Tags: python, celery

How can I run a celery task at a given time, but only once?

I read the documentation and couldn't find any example of this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### If you insist on using Celery

To run a task at a specified time, in Celery you would normally use a [*periodic task*](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html), which conventionally is a recurring task.

However, you may create a periodic task with a very specific schedule and condition that happens only once so effectively it runs only once.

Unfortunately we can only [specify](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.schedules.html#celery.schedules.crontab) so much, e.g. we can specify `hour`, `minute`, `day_of_month` and `month_of_year` but we can't specify `year`

However with that, your task would run at most 1 time for per year, so below are some workarounds:

**Unschedule it after it is ran**

It should be relatively easy to *unschedule* it once it is ran (you have 1 year to do so!)

**Use a "DONE" flag when the task completes**

With a flag written somewhere (disk or DB), you can first check if the task has run before or not, i.e. `if done: exit`

**Exit if not proper year**
or you want to be safe, just add code into the task that checks the year, e.g. `if year != 2017: exit`.

### Simple cron/Os level scheduler works too

You may also skip Celery altogether and use some OS level facility like cron for UNIX-like systems, [more on that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473780/how-to-setup-cron-to-run-a-file-just-once-at-a-specific-time-in-future).

The general idea remains the same.

Comment: Ok i'll do: periodic task runs every 1min, task looks up on redis for if it has been ran, if not, executes task over celery

Answer (score 52):

You can use parameter `eta` when calling the task. Example:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

@app.task()
def hello(self):
    return 'hello world'


tomorrow = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=1)
hello.apply_async(eta=tomorrow)
```

Documentation: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#eta-and-countdown

**Alternatively**, when you want to call `hello` multiple times *and* to be sure it is executed only one at the time, you can use locking - more about it in the documentation: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html#ensuring-a-task-is-only-executed-one-at-a-time

Answer (score 5):

There is a boolean field called `one_off` in PeriodicTask. Set it to `true` for running celery tasks only once at the given time.

Example(following code is the dynamic task creation part in `views.py`):

```
def test():
    schedule, created = CrontabSchedule.objects.get_or_create(hour=20, minute=6, day_of_month=1, month_of_year=9)
    task = PeriodicTask.objects.create(crontab = schedule, name = 'somename', task = 'core.tasks.methodnameintasks', one_off=True)
```

However, the task remains enabled until the celery beat is updated. A new task creation or update in the existing tasks will solve this problem.