# How to use celery running task only once at a specific time？

Tags: django, queue, celery

I want to design a task queues in Django, the queues are ordered by a time tag with the task and the task will be executed only once at the specific time. So I want to use Celery to implement it. But what haunt me is that Celery only has the crontab ability which running tasks at every day, month, week, etc.
So how to implelement the queue with Celery?

Comment: "Celery only has the crontab ability". Its wrong

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41568305/celery-run-task-once-at-a-specified-time

Comment: I have read the Celery document in detail and found the answer: the apply_async((args), eta=datetime.utcnow()+timedelta(hours=1)) function could solve my problem