# how can I run celery task only once in django?

Tags: python, django, cron, celery, django-celery

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from celery import shared_task
from celery.task import periodic_task
from celery.schedules import crontab
from datetime import timedelta



@periodic_task(run_every=(crontab(minute='*/1')), name='greeting_task')
def greeting_task():
    print('hello Dias!')
```

Can I create a function that runs only once at certain time with crontab? PLEASE, HELP!!!
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the parameters for `crontab`.

Example: If you want the task to be run once at 5AM everyday:

```
@periodic_task(run_every=(crontab(minute='0', hour='5')), name='greeting_task')
def greeting_task():
    print('hello Dias!')
```

`crontab(minute='*/1')` will run the task at every minute. Read about crontab syntax here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: not everyday, only once at 5:00 for example, and only today, not tomorrow and so one, only once! Is it possible?

Comment: Ah I see, this link might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41568305/celery-run-task-once-at-a-specified-time

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Django-Celery-Beat](https://django-celery-beat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), it has the ability to create tasks that run *only once* at a specific date/time using the [`ClockedSchedule`](http://%20https://django-celery-beat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/django_celery_beat/models.html#ClockedSchedule) model. It's not in the documentation for some reason but you can easily configure it through the Django Admin.